# How to parse xml.gz in golang

Tags: xml, email, go, attachment, gzip

I am new to Golang.
I want to parse email attachment which is in format of xml.gz.
I am not getting how can i manipulate string which i am getting in a.data
How can i achieve this in golang?

My CODE:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "io"
    _ "compress/gzip"
    "github.com/DusanKasan/parsemail"
)

var reader io.Reader
var err error

func main() {
    fmt.Println("HIII.. THIS IS TESTING")
    reader, err = os.Open("4.raw")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    email, err := parsemail.Parse(reader)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    for _, a := range(email.Attachments) {
        r, _ := gzip.NewReader(a.Data)
        io.Copy(os.Stdout, r)
        r.Close()
    }
}
```

Now I am getting XML formatted data on terminal.
But I want same data in variable

when I print r, it shows me something like &{[31 139 8 0 89 139 65 92 0 3 237 157 205 114 226 56 16 128 207 187 79 193 206 61 50 146 255 1 ...... ]}

Comment: use compress gzip to convert the a.Data to uncompressed bytes then use encoding/xml on that to extract the content

Comment: It is not clear where your problems actually are. Do you have problems extracting the attachment, decompressing the `*.gz` or processing the `*.xml` (whatever the result of this processing should be)?

Comment: I am getting data in a.data.
but it is something like &{[31 139 8 0 89 139 65 92 0 3 237 157 205 114 226 56 16 128 207 187 79 193 206 61 50 146 255 1......]}

i want this should be XML data...

while writing to STDOUT it is showing me in xml format, but when i use fmt.Println it is coming as numbers...

I am not getting how can i parse this ?

please suggest, i am new to golang

Comment: Simply pass the gzip.Reader to [encoding/xml.NewDecoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#NewDecoder), then call [Decode](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Decoder.Decode).